# how to use ng-if inside element with ui-view?

Tags: angularjs, show

I want to show a view depending of certain model, I'm using ng-if to achieve it, but I cant get it.

I have the following

```
div.detail(ui-view="detail" ng-if="consultation.detail")
div.geolocation(ui-view="geolocation" ng-if="!consultation.detail")
```

**So, inside my controller I initially have vm.detail = true, hence the first div it is showing, but when I want to change the value of vm.detail to false (with ng-click event with a link), the first div is hidden, and the second one, is hidden too, and it no should be that! it shoud be showing the second div
What Am I doing wrong?**